# rbenv not using the shims Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rbenv

I am using Ubuntu 12.10 and I am trying to get my project up and running using rbenv and bundler.

I have successfully installed rbenv from the apt repository and installed the required version of ruby using ruby-build.

When I run `which gem` I get the global `/usr/bin/gem` that I assume came with the apt repository install. However when I run rbenv which gem I get the proper local gem `/home/kasuko/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/bin/gem`

However when I run `gem install bundler` I get an error on permissions with "Permission denied - /var/lib/gems" which leads me to believe that it is using the global gem.

So when I run `/home/kasuko/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/bin/gem install bundler` it successfully installs bundler

I do have the rbenv init line in my `~/.zshrc.local (which is sourced in my ~/.zshrc)` and I get the updated path  `"/home/kasuko/.rbenv/shims:/home/kasuko/.bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"` so I'm pretty sure it's installed correctly.

So why aren't my rbenv shims being used?

Thanks
Kasuko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not sure which `gem` is being executed, try `gem env` which will show you useful information about the version of `gem` you're running, such as the rubygems version, corresponding ruby executable, gem paths and other good stuff.

Your PATH seems correct.  Try running `hash -r` to clear the shell's cache of executable paths just in case.

Once you've done this, `which gem` should give you `/home/kasuko/.rbenv/shims/gem`, which would indicate that it's deferring to rbenv to determine the actual executable to run.

You may then need to run `rbenv rehash`.  This should be run every time you install a new gem with an executable (like bundler, rake, etc).  It will update all the shims to point to the correct executables.

Comment: Yep, it appears it must have been a caching issue. I had rebooted my computer recently and when I went to execute your answer it showed that it was now the shim gem already.

Comment: Yeah, bash only remembers the locations of executables within the same shell, I think, so then rehashing is not necessary.